# How to play simple fading animation with movement of button in XCode Swift 5

Tags: xcode, swift5

I was trying to animate button in xcode in viewDidAppear():

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.button.frame.origin.y -= 90
        self.button.frame.origin.x -= 10

}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    button.alpha=0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In viewWillAppear() firstly set alpha of button to 0 then in viewDidAppear animate it as follows:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
        self.button.alpha = 1
        self.button.frame.origin.y -= 90
        self.button.frame.origin.x -= 10
    }
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    button.alpha=0
}
```